# iterate to perform calculations on certain column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration

I am working with a large pandas dataframe where I have created a new empty column.  What I want to do si to iterate over every value within a specific column of the dataframe, do a Boolean check, and then assign a value to the new column based on the output of the value check.

I would think I need to use a for loop to check the individual contents of each cell in my specified column.  The problem is that I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to correctly write a for loop that checks values in a specific column.  This is what I have so far.

---

```
call_info['% of Net Capital'] = call_info['Call Amount'] / call_info['Net Capital']

for (ColumnData) in call_info['Call Amount']:
    columnSeriesObj = call_info[ColumnData]
    if columnSeriesObj.any - call_info['Excess Deficit'].any > 0:
       call_info['Sufficient Excess?'][ColumnData] = True
    else:
        call_info['Sufficient Excess?'][ColumnData] = False
```

I get a KeyError : 38749372

call_info is a pandas dataframe.  I am trying to compare call_info['Call Amount'] against call_info['Excess Deficit'] and put a True or false value in call_info['Sufficient Excess?']

**Updated to include an example of my dataframe, and the expected output

This is a snip of a larger csv file:
[image: CSV File Output]

I have loaded the data from this CSV file using openpyxl load_workbook
From there, I converted the data into a Pandas Dataframe using the following code :

```
from itertools import islice
data = sheet_ranges.values
cols = next(data)[1:]
data = list(data)
idx = [r[0] for r in data]
data = (islice(r, 1, None) for r in data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)
```

An example of the expected output is a column within the dataframe that looks like this:
[image: Expected output]

I've been able to do this in Excel, but I am looking to automate the process

Comment: Can you provide an example of your dataframe please? As well as the expected result

Comment: I just updated for clarity.  Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some demo data, which hopefully represents the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size = [20, 2]), columns = ['call_amount', 'excess_deficit'])
```

Then you can use the following code to get the result your looking for.

```
df['sufficient_excess'] = (df['call_amount'] - df['excess_deficit']) > 0
```

which gives

```
    call_amount excess_deficit  sufficient_excess
0           684            559               True
1           629            192               True
2           835            763               True
3           707            359               True
4             9            723              False
5           277            754              False
6           804            599               True
7            70            472              False
8           600            396               True
9           314            705              False
```

If you need the result changing to have `Yes` instead of `True`, let me now

Comment: Ahah! I didn't realize you could simply compare the entire columns against each other like that. Thank you

Comment: Yeah pandas is great for these kinds of problems :)